# ¿Como puedo crear un mixin de Sass (.scss) que "simplifique" el siguiente código CSS?

Tags: scss

El código fuente está en CSS. ¿Cómo hago para "simplificarlo" con un mixin en código Sass (.scss)?

```
.is-1-of-1-xs {
    width: 100%;
}

.is-1-of-2-xs {
    width: 50%;
}

.is-1-of-3-xs {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.is-2-of-3-xs {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.is-1-of-4-xs {
    width: 25%;
}

.is-3-of-4-xs {
    width: 75%;
}

.is-1-of-5-xs {
    width: 20%;
}

.is-2-of-5-xs {
    width: 40%;
}

.is-3-of-5-xs {
    width: 60%;
}

.is-4-of-5-xs {
    width: 80%;
}
```

¿Cómo hago para que el mixin no repita estilos?, es decir, no puede existir la clase:

```
.is-2-of-4-xs {
    width: 50%;
}
```

¿Y como hago para que escriba estilos para los breakpoints "xs", "sm", "md", "lg" y "xl"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para los breakpoints puedes usar esto:

```
$breakpoints: (
    md: 576px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1392px,
);

@mixin mq($breakpoint) {
    @media screen and (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, $breakpoint)) {
        @content;
    }
}

@include mq(lg) {
  .clase {
    // reglas css
  }
}
```

para crear las clases:

```
@mixin ancho($columnas, $sufix: "") {
    $ancho: 100% / $columnas;

    @for $columna from 1 through $columnas {
        .is-#{$columna}-of-#{$columnas}-#{$sufix} {
            width: $ancho * $columna;
        }
    }
}
```

Y luego usalos juntos:

```
@include mq(md) {
    @include ancho(6, md)
}

@include mq(lg) {
    @include ancho(12, lg)
}
```

Para que no se repitan las clases no tengo una solución.

Comment: Buena respuesta! Que no se repitan las clases creo que es complicarse sin sentido. Y se simplificó un montón el código. Gracias!